# Uncaught OAuthException: (#200) User is not in an allowed country for this app's music functionality, nor a tester or developer of the app

Tags: facebook, authentication, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-apps

When I log in with my facebook account in my website, sucess! But when log in with facebook account of my friend, give this error: Uncaught OAuthException: (#200) User is not in an allowed country for this app's music functionality, nor a tester or developer of the app.
It's not just him. The other people also.
In the settings of the app I put as "people without location can use" and "people from any location can use", but continues giving the error.

Comment: Sounds like the App is still in Sandbox mode. Check Sandbox Mode setting under Basic Settings.

Comment: Is there any chance at all that the app is trying to post music actions which haven't been approved by Facebook? Because that's what the error means

Comment: The sandbox mode is off
and the app works correctly in my account, put the songs usually

Comment: Problem resolved. It was because there was a move that needed the approval of Facebook can be used for

Comment: Would be awesome if you'd share the solution with the other poor fellas...

Comment: The solution was this, contact the Facebook to they approves your app.